# I have imported app component in app.module.ts file but still is not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli

`'app-header'` is not a known element:

1. If `'app-header'` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `'app-header'` is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("wrapper">   
     [ERROR ->]

Comment: please edit your question and add `app.module.ts` code

Answer (score 2):

this error related to `angular-cli` you have `'app-header'` component and use it, but this component not a part of any module in your application.
for fix this error define this component in your `app.module.ts` file like this:

> add your component class name in `declarations` section

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppHeader
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your component in the module? For example:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    VideosComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Note this sample doesn't use your app-header component.

Answer (score 0):

There should be many reasons for this error. You can check below point to solve this error.

1) check the selector name declared in component and used name
2) app-header component must be declared in some module in declarations
3) If there is some another module for app-header, then import that module in your current module
4) restart the server after each change (may be in some case)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:I am new to ang2
I had a mismatch b/w selector name and the tag name in app.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-home',

})  in my my-home.component.ts and i was trying <'my-home'>in app.component.ts. As i changed to <'app-my-home'> , it worked